# Remove Paragraph from ItemList

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have lots of GDocs that have a mess in their numbering. Part of the docs where copied from other docs, parts from Word documents (docx).

To clean up, I want to loop over a document and remove the numbering. I am able to loop over the paragraphs and identify header paragraphs, so I can cleanup numbering that is part of the text itself (at the beginning of the line), not problem.

But most of the paragraphs get their numbering from the "Bullets and Numbering" option. I learned that those paragraphs are part of the ListItem collection (is this an array?) and I am able to loop over that also. I can set the type by using `setGlyphType`, but that's not what I want, I want no type at all.

I thought maybe removing it from the list could solve this, but the only method I found was `RemoveFromParent` which deletes the whole paragraph.

When I'm in the document, I have to click at the beginning of the paragraph and press Backspace twice, but I can't find any method to remove the numbering from a paragraph per script.

[image]

Comment: Since you can already access the `ListItem`, I think a workaround you can do is 1. get the parent. 2. get the text equivalent of the bulleted element. 3. remove the bulleted element from parent. 4. insert a paragraph there containing the text of the element you just copied. You might have a need to format the added paragraph but I think that should do. I'll try to test the concept and provide you an answer if I'm successful.

Comment: @ASyntuBU Interesting attempt, but this feels so *wrong*.

Comment: I have made it work below @FunThomas. Check if it works on you.

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully implemented the workaround above.

#### Script:

```
function Remove_Bullets() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  for (var i = 0; i < body.getNumChildren(); i++) {
    var element = body.getChild(i);
    if (element.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM) {
      element.getParent().asBody()
             .insertParagraph(i, element.asText().getText())
             .setAttributes(element.getAttributes());
      element.removeFromParent();
    }
  }
}
```

#### Sample:

[image: sample]

#### Turned into:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Some formatting wasn't applied properly due to it being stored in bullet/header settings but basic attributes were applied nevertheless.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all of your effort. I upvoted it, although it doesn't really solved my issues - while the numbering is gone, the lines stay indented and therefore I still have to go thru my documents manually. Maybe the real task is not feasible with apps script. The more I dig into App Script the more I have the impression that Google supports it very half hearted.

Comment: A bit weird. Sorry wasn't able to solve your issue though.